# Displaying the place/location name instead of the ID

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I am trying to filter and display my friends status updates that have a location/place included in the post.  I've tried many iterations, but cannot get the location to display (other than the place 'id'.  I want to display only status updates posted by friends where an actual location was included.  I have tried changing the object from 'stream' to 'place' and 'location_post' with no luck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is the code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '<?= $sApplicationId ?>',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
    });

    function updateButton(response) {
        var button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');

        if (response.authResponse) {
            var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
            var iPid = 0;
            FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                userInfo.innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture">' + response.name;
                button.innerHTML = 'Logout';

                // get friends activity feed
                iPid = response.id;
                if (iPid > 0) {
                    FB.api({ // call fql.query
                        method: 'fql.query',
                        query: "SELECT post_id, actor_id, type, description, place, permalink, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE      uid = me() AND type = 'newsfeed') ORDER BY place DESC"
                    }, function (response) {

                        $('#results').html(
                        $('#facebookTemplate').render(response));
                    });
                }
            });

            button.onclick = function () {
                FB.logout(function (response) {
                    window.location.reload();
                });
            };
        } else {
            button.onclick = function () {
                FB.login(function (response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                }, {
                    scope: 'read_stream'
                });
            }
        }
    }

    FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);
};

(function () {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to show? Post info mixed with place info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's no direct way to do this, but you can join the post and the place info on the client side:

Posts:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, type, description, place, permalink, message from stream where post_id in (select post_id from location_post where author_uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) and post_id)
```

Places:

```
SELECT page_id, location from page where page_id in (select page_id from location_post where author_uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) and post_id)
```

The join should be on the `posts.place = places.page_id` keys.